# Why does the sound skip in ALSA?

Tags: c, audio, alsa, libalsa

I am trying to play [this sound](http://mauvecloud.net/sounds/pcm1611s.wav) using the program below, but the sound is a little fast and it skips. The sound file's sample rate is 11025 Hz, stereo, the sample size is 16 bit. The issue appears to be `snd_pcm_hw_params_set_buffer_size()` and `snd_pcm_hw_params_set_period_size()` (both are functions I am studying) due to invalid arguments, but I don't know why they are invalid and commenting them out doesn't address the skipping effect. What am I doing wrong?

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <alsa/asoundlib.h>

#define STEREO              2
#define BITS            16 / 8
#define FRAMEBUFFERSIZE   512 // in samples
#define PERIODS             2
#define SAMPLERATE      11025

void snd_error_checker(int error, char *function_name)
{
    if (error)
    {
        printf("Error (%s): %s\n", function_name, snd_strerror(error));
        // exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    snd_pcm_t *handle;
    uint32_t channels                   = STEREO;
    uint32_t sample_size                = BITS; // 16 bit
    uint32_t frame_size                 = sample_size * channels;
    snd_pcm_uframes_t frames            = FRAMEBUFFERSIZE / frame_size;
    snd_pcm_uframes_t frames_per_period = frames / PERIODS;
    int32_t dir = 0; // No idea what this does.
    snd_pcm_hw_params_t *params;
    int16_t *buffer;
    FILE *wav;
    int32_t size;
    int error;

    error = snd_pcm_open(&handle, "default", SND_PCM_STREAM_PLAYBACK, 0);
    snd_error_checker(error, "snd_pcm_open()");
    snd_pcm_hw_params_alloca(&params);
    error = snd_pcm_hw_params_any(handle, params);
    snd_error_checker(error, "snd_pcm_hw_params_any()");
    error = snd_pcm_hw_params_set_buffer_size(handle, params, frames);
    snd_error_checker(error, "snd_pcm_hw_params_set_buffer_size()");
    error = snd_pcm_hw_params_set_period_size(handle, params, frames_per_period, dir);
    snd_error_checker(error, "snd_pcm_hw_params_set_period_size()");
    error = snd_pcm_hw_params_set_rate(handle, params, SAMPLERATE, dir);
    snd_error_checker(error, "snd_pcm_hw_params_set_rate()");
    error = snd_pcm_hw_params_set_access(handle, params, SND_PCM_ACCESS_RW_INTERLEAVED);
    snd_error_checker(error, "snd_pcm_hw_params_set_access()");
    error = snd_pcm_hw_params_set_channels(handle, params, STEREO);
    snd_error_checker(error, "snd_pcm_hw_params_set_channels()");
    error = snd_pcm_hw_params_set_format(handle, params, SND_PCM_FORMAT_S16_LE);
    snd_error_checker(error, "snd_pcm_hw_params_set_format()");
    error = snd_pcm_hw_params(handle, params);
    snd_error_checker(error, "snd_pcm_hw_params()");

    // Insert samples to framebuffer.
    wav = fopen("pcm1611s.wav", "r");
    fseek(wav, 0L, SEEK_END);
    size = ftell(wav);
    fseek(wav, 0L, SEEK_SET);
    buffer = malloc(size);
    fread(buffer, sizeof(int16_t), size, wav);
    fclose(wav);
    size /= sizeof(int16_t);

    // Set ptrbuffer 46 bytes ahead to skip the header.
    for (int16_t *ptrbuffer = buffer + 46; size > ptrbuffer - buffer; ptrbuffer += FRAMEBUFFERSIZE * STEREO * BITS)
    {
        error = snd_pcm_writei(handle, ptrbuffer, frames);
        if (error)
        {
            snd_pcm_recover(handle, error, 0);
        }
    }
    snd_pcm_drain(handle);
    snd_pcm_close(handle);
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Comment: Where do you decode the wav-file header?

Comment: I have moved `fread()` out of the loop, added error checking to all `snd_pcm_*` functions, made it skip what I believe to be  the header which appears to be 44-46 bytes long. I feel like the question will be a lot harder to read because of these changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#define FRAMEBUFFERSIZE   512 // in samples
```

The comment is lying; the value is used as a byte count.

```
uint32_t sample_size                = BITS; // 16 bit
```

The comment is lying; the value is actualy measured in bytes. (And `BITS` is named wrong.)

```
fread(buffer, sizeof(int16_t), size, wav);
```

`size` is measured in bytes, but you tell `fread()` to read 16-bit words. (This does not actually hurt because it stops reading at the end of the file. But you should have checked for errors.)

```
int16_t *ptrbuffer = ...
```

You are telling the compiler that `ptrbuffer` points to 16-bit values.

```
ptrbuffer += FRAMEBUFFERSIZE * STEREO * BITS
```

You are telling the compiler to step over 2048 16-bit values, i.e., over 4096 bytes. You actually want to step over all the sample in a buffer, that is, `frames * STEREO`.

```
error = snd_pcm_writei(...);
if (error)
```

`snd_pcm_writei()` returns a positive number on success; errors are negative.

Answer (score 1):

Three points need to be consider for proper playback

1. Check return value of `snd_pcm_writei` , will give a clear idea , whats going wrong if any error. Refer[alsa-project](https://www.alsa-project.org/alsa-doc/alsa-lib/group___p_c_m.html#gabc748a500743713eafa960c7d104ca6f)
2. Reading file in `while()` loop and giving to `snd_pcm_writei` can cause skip in audio with under run (`-EPIPE` error), since `fread` is time consuming call.
3. Check return values of all of your library calls and make sure all are success.
   Also make sure the values are setting properly in driver . For example, after `snd_pcm_hw_params_set_rate` verify it with `snd_pcm_hw_params_get_rate`, if your driver is not supporting sampling rate 11025KHz, we can find out it with return values and rechecking with `snd_pcm_hw_params_get_rate`

Comment: I have used return values to locate the error and I have found that `snd_pcm_hw_params_set_buffer_size()` and `snd_pcm_hw_params_set_period_size()` returns "Invalid argument" as error. Not very descriptive or clarifying but at least I know where the error is.